# Connecting two subnets

Tags: networking, router, lan, subnet

I have two linksys routers connected together LAN to WAN and I'm trying to establish connection between the two subnets.

The secondary router is in a shed not in my house. I'd rather not do LAN to LAN as that would take up a port on the router. This is a learning experience for me so I'd rather not take the easy way out. I've learned a lot while trying to get it working.

Here's my setup:
[image: Network Image]

I can not ping (computer A) to (computer B).
I can not ping (computer B) to (computer A).
From (computer A) I can not access the secondary router.
From (computer B) I can access both routers.

Both Routers have a DVR camera system hooked up to them, they have local IPs for viewing the cameras and I can access both DVRs from either computer.

I want to be able to ping computer A and computer B from either router (want to be able to transfer files)

I have looked at so many guides and information but nothing seems to work.

P.S. I cant even access the secondary router from computer A. if i type 192.168.1.134 or 192.168.7.7 in the browser it dont load

Comment: The LAN interface in main router and the WAN interface in the secondary MUST have different IP addresses of the same subnet.

Comment: Move Comp2 to Router2's DMZ.

Comment: I dont understand how the LAN on the main router and the WAN on the second router have to have different IPs of the same subnet. The LAN of the main router is giving 192.168.1.134 to the WAN of the secondary router. essentualy making 192.168.1.134 the internet IP of the secondary router.

I cant even enable DMZ on the second router. but i need the problem fixed on the whole subnet. not just per pc. i have a lot more stuff connected to the subnets than just pcs, such as servailance systems. small rapsberry pi servers ect ect

Answer (score 1):

From the diagram, your IP addressing and routing appear to be fine.

- Although you marked on the diagram that the secondary router has "SPI firewall" disabled, I'd double-check whether there is any other firewall configuration; perhaps *reenable* the firewall and just explicitly configure it to accept everything. If you're lucky, the firewall rules might even come with logging, so that the router's "system log" section would show all mistakenly-blocked packets.
- It's also possible that the firewall on the *main* router might be interfering; e.g. it might only have an allow-forward rule for "192.168.1.x to WAN".
- Another possible problem is that the primary router might not want to forward routed packets back to the same interface that they already came from (i.e. from LAN to LAN). I don't know why some routers do that, but it's apparently a thing that happens.

To rule out the latter two problems, I suggest temporarily adding the same route (192.168.7.0/24 via 192.168.1.134) *to computer A* (thereby bypassing the Main Router entirely).

The secondary router's "NAT" rules (SNAT or masquerading) shouldn't interfere with incoming connections, but it's still good that you've disabled NAT regardless.

---

If you run out of LAN ports, buy an Ethernet switch.

Comment: the secondary router is a Linksys WRT320N, theres not many options when it comes to the firewall, just enable or disable. plus these options underneath '*Filter Anonymous Internet Requests *Filter Multicast *Filter Multicast *Filter IDENT (Port 113)' theres not many other options on the second router eather. its a Linksys EA8500